# Cómo puedo adaptar el código javascript para que siga una jerarquía?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, javascript-objeto

compañeros:

Estoy realizando un proyecto con django3 y tengo el siguiente problema al querer mostrar los formularios siguiendo una cierta jerarquía, tengo 3
formularios, 1 de ellos los renderizo utilizando ModelForm y los otros 2 con inlineformset_factory .

Los modelos que tengo son: persona, dirección, telefono, donde dirección hace referencia a persona y telefóno a dirección, por lo que una persona puede tner varias direcciones y cada dirección varios telefónos

Aunque los formularios renderizados con inlineformset_factory (dirección y telefóno) se muestran y los guardo correctamente, no logro que en el template siga la siguiente jerarquía cuando el usuario agrega más campos tanto de forms1(dirección) y forms2(telefóno):
1. dirección
1.1 telefóno
1.2 Telefóno
1.3 telefóno
2. dirección 2
2.1 telefóno
2.2 telefono
3. dirección 3
3.1 telefóno
3.2 telefono
3.3 Telefóno
...

Pero lo que tengo actualmente es:
1. dirección
2. dirección 2
3. direcció 3
1.1 tlefono
1.2 telefono
1.3 telefono
2.1 telefono
2.2
3.1 telefono telefono
3.2 telefono
3.3 telefono
...

el código de donde tome el ejemplo es: https://github.com/adandan01/mybook

y el código de mi template es el siguiente, aclarando que form son los que renderizon con ModelForm:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block title %}Crear proyecto{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    {% include "projects/includes/menu.html" %}
    <main role="main">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-9 mx-auto">
        <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-row mt-5">
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </div>

            <table class="table">
                {{ forms1.management_form }}

                {% for form in forms1.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </table>

            <table class="table">
                {{ forms2.management_form }}

                {% for form in forms2.forms %}
                    {% if forloop.first %}
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                    {% endif %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle row1 row2 %} formset_row1">
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <td>
                                {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                {% if forloop.first %}
                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endif %}
                                {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                                {{ field }}
                            </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
    </table>

            <div class="row" id="anchor">
            </div>

            <div class="form-row mt-5">
                {{form3.as_table}}
            </div>
          <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Crear proyecto" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </main>
    <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.formset_row').formset({

            addText: 'Añadir dirección',
            deleteText: 'Borrar dirección',
            prefix: 'direccion_set'
        });

            $('.formset_row1').formset({
            addText: 'Añadir telefóno Secundario',
            deleteText: 'Borrar telefóno',
            prefix: 'telf_set'
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Si alguno me puede orientar por donde deben ir mis pasos, para lograr la jerarquía que deseo, se lo agradecería, saludos.